# How should date strings be handled when rendering on both server and client?

Tags: javascript, date, next.js, formatting, luxon

I am creating a blog using NextJS and [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/).

1. I want to include the post creation date in HTML when a post is rendered by the server, so that the Google crawler has that information.
2. I also want the creation date to display in a suitable format for the end user. I am using the [luxon package](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=formatting) which formats to the user's timezone and locale automatically

The server does not know where the end user's request is coming from - I don't want to format the date to the user's locale during SSR

...but if there is a difference between the server rendered content and the client rendered content, I get a [react-hydration-error](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error)

What is the recommended approach for rendering date strings on both server and client?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the date the server and pass it to the client-side as a prop, then format it again to your desired format using luxon. With this method, you can use the formatted date in your HTML for the Google crawler as well as the user, without any difference in the information received by either. This should also avoid the hydration error.

Here is an example:

```
// server-side:
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const creationDate = DateTime.utc().toISO();

  return {
    props: {
      creationDate,
    },
  };
}

// client-side:
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

const Post = ({ creationDate }) => {
  const formattedCreationDate = DateTime.fromISO(creationDate)
    .setLocale('en-US')
    .toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_FULL);

  return (
    <>
      <p>{formattedCreationDate}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Comment: You don't need Luxon for any of that. `new Date().toISOString()` gets the current UTC date as ISO 8601. Given that string, `new Date(isoString).toLocaleString('en-US')` formats it according to the en-US language with the date and time based on the host regional settings (i.e. local).

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to render the date on server side. You can wrap it in a "NoSsr" component like the one by material ui:

```
<NoSsr> {(DateTime string that won't match server side)} </NoSsr>
```

You can use Material UI's NoSsr or create your own.

OR, since the hydration errors are caused by the timezones being different on server and client you can force set the timezone:

```
DateTime.fromJSDate(date).setZone("utc").toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_FULL)
```

Comment: Sorry neither of these answers are suitable since they dont satisfy the 2 requirements in my question